# Capture value from loop in callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, closures

I have a loop which performs an async get method which calls a callback when completed. In the callback, I need to know which loop the callback was linked to.

I'm guessing this might be to do with closures, but don't really understand what I need to change to capture the key from the for loop.

Side note: I'm aware looping through Redis keys is generally bad practice, but there are only a handful of keys in this case.

```
 let redisGetCallback = function(err, getResponse) {
  numberOfLoops++;
  let user = JSON.parse(getResponse);

  if(user.uid === userInfo.uid) {
    user.grantedPermission = true;
    let userSerialised = JSON.stringify(user);

    redis.set('!!NeedTheKeyFromTheForLoopBelowHere!!', userSerialised.....

  } else if (numberOfLoops === numberOfKeys) {
    cb(false);
  }
};

for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  redis.get(keys[i], redisGetCallback);
}
```

Comment: You should go for promises.

Comment: So would this be correct? 
`for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
      redis.get(keys[i]).
          then(function(result) {
            let user = JSON.parse(result);

            user.grantedPermission = true;
            redis.set(keys[i], userSerialised, .....
          });
    }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know the value of `i` in the given callback then instead of:

```
for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  redis.get(keys[i], redisGetCallback);
}
```

run it with:

```
for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  redis.get(keys[i], redisGetCallback(i));
}
```

and change your `redisGetCallback` from:

```
let redisGetCallback = function(err, getResponse) {
};
```

to:

```
let redisGetCallback = number => (err, getResponse) => {
};
```

and you'll have the correct number available as `number` inside of your callback.

Of course the may be other problems with your implementation so you may need to make more changes, but the basic ideas is that instead of relying on the global variables it's better to pass the correct values as parameters.

Remember that you never know the order in which the callbacks will be called so your last callback may be called first and if you count the number of the callback in the order it is run it doesn't necessarily be the same as the number of the callback in the order it was registered.

Comment: Thanks, so in each loop a function is run with an index passed in and this function returns a function with parameters that redis expects to callback to, but with the index captured in the parent function?

Also I understand that callbacks can occur in any order, but what do you meant by the number of callbacks run it doesn't necessarily be the same as the number of callback registered? Is this because we can't rely on the method actually calling back?

Comment: @Si-N My mistake: "the number of callbacks" should be "the number of the callback" - good catch. And yes, you have a function that takes a parameter `number` and returns a new function that takes some other parameters and has access to the outer function parameter. The arrow function makes it easier with `a => b => c` instead of `function (a) { return function (b) { return c; } }` - I have a crazy example in one of my projects where I have 7 functions defined in a single line here  https://github.com/rsp/node-mijs/blob/master/index.js#L21